# While loop error when uploading $_FILES

Tags: php, arrays, file, while-loop

I'm looking to upload multiple files to a folder once all of the conditions are met successfully. I'm allowing the user to choose how many files they'd like to upload, however am receiving this error from the script:

`Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\FreeCheese\news_parse.php on line 54`

**Note:**

The number following 'Undefined offset:', in this case is set to '1'. When I chose to insert more file fields into the page this number becomes whatever the number of current file fields are being read by the PHP.

**EG: I have three file fields, the error would then become:**

`Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\FreeCheese\news_parse.php on line 54`

If I **do** select three files to upload, all of them are being correctly inserted into the folder, so I have no idea why I am being given an error when it is functioning as it should.

If anyone could help me fix this error then it'd be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Rich

**Here is my code:**

```
// Set the array object to 0 when entering the loop.
$i = 0;
while ($_FILES['upload1']['tmp_name'][$i]) {
$imgName1 = preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9.]#i", "", $_FILES['upload1']['name'][$i]);

// Applies a unique number before the file name to prevent files from overwriting.
$imgName1 = mt_rand(100000, 999999).$imgName1;

// Moves the image into the images/ folder
move_uploaded_file($imgTmp1[$i], "images/$imgName1");

// Sets the next array object in the loop to 1 etc etc
   $i ++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are 5 files, then `$_FILES['upload1']['tmp_name'][5]` won't exist, so the `while` condition crashes (it doesn't return false !)...
You have to check `count($_FILES['upload1']['tmp_name'])` !

```
$nbFiles = count($_FILES['upload1']['tmp_name']);
while ($i < $nbFiles) {
    [...your code...]
    $i++;
}
```

You should also use a `for` loop, since it is made for what you need :

```
$nbFiles = count($_FILES['upload1']['tmp_name']);
for ($i=0; $i < $nbFiles; $i++) {
    [...your code...]
}
```

Comment: You're a beautiful human being. Cheers man. >_< I'll accept your answer in 9 mins, thanks for the fast response.

Comment: Irony is, he is a random guy @Filthy_Rich

Comment: Do you think it'd be safe to use an SQL query within this while loop to insert the file path to the database?

Comment: @Filthy_Rich What do you mean ?